# How to accurately show a framed page in my mobile simulator

Tags: iframe, resize

It seems to me that there are some javascript guru's here, which I am not.

I would like to accurately display framed sites on a mobile simulator that I am building. It is located temporarily here at http://mobilewaythemes.com/mobile/mobile_simulator/.
I am not using this page to show how a mobile enabled site looks on an iPhone! I actually want to show my clients how their "desktop site" looks on a mobile device.

I have removed the scrollbars from the iframe script that I am using but I need to render how my customers sites actually look miniature in mobile devices. I hope you're following me, sorry, I am not a professional developer. Would someone please take a quick look and possibly tell me how to do this?

I found this javascript (squeezeFrame.js) which I thought might be helpful and I added it to the page but it is currently not functional.

Thank you in advance for your time!
Sincerely,
Brent Wallace